# Correct use of Null-Conditional Operator with DateTime.Parse()

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a string to a `DateTime?` using `DateTime.Parse()` but only when the string is not null. I'm trying to use the **Null-Conditional Operator**

This is what I'm trying to replace:

```
string maxPermissableEndDate = response.Contract.ReferenceFields.FirstOrDefault(t => t.code == "MAX_EXT_DATE")?.Value;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(maxPermissableEndDate))
{
     contract.MaximumPermissableEndDate = DateTime.Parse(maxPermissableEndDate);
}
```

How can I assign to the nullable DateTime property MaximumPermissableEndDate in this attractive way **only** when the variable maxPermissableEndDate is not null?

This is the example I'm looking at from the  C# 6.0 documentation:

```
string result = value;

if (value != null) // Skip empty string check for elucidation
{
  result = value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
}
```

With the alternative being:

```
value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, length));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like:

```
contract.MaximumPermissableEndDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(maxPermissableEndDate) ?
     contract.MaximumPermissableEndDate 
    : new Nullable<DateTime>(DateTime.Parse(maxPermissableEndDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use the null coalesce operator, but something like this?

```
DateTime attemptParseDate;
contract.MaximumPermissableEndDate = 
 DateTime.TryParse(maxPermissableEndDate, out attemptParseDate)?
  attemptParseDate : (DateTime?) null;
```